# Java Thread communication

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

In java Thread I can easily communicate between two thread using `wait()` and `notify()`.

But suppose I have 10 thread running say `T1` to `T10` and I want thread `T2` to communicate with thread `T7`.

how I can do this? some example will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I'd suggest not messing with threads in a JavaEE (especially EJB) container - the more so if you're not familiar with how they work. There's probably are more JavaEE like solution so please elaborate.

Comment: short answer is that you can't. By using notifyAll you don't know in advance which thread is going to be executed next

Answer (score 5):

Communication between threads is possible with wait/notify but very complex (to get it right), especially when more than two threads is involved.

The more modern solution of [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)s is far better suited to inter-thread communications in Java.

To use them, create a queue that is to be shared between the two threads before the threads are created. Then pass the queue to each thread as it is created. They then both keep hold of the queue, one writes to it and the other reads.

```
public class TwoThreads {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("TwoThreads:Test");
        new TwoThreads().test();
    }

    // The end of the list.
    private static final Integer End = -1;

    static class Producer implements Runnable {

        final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

        public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    queue.add(i);
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
                // Finish the queue.
                queue.add(End);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Just exit.
            }
        }

    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable {

        final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

        public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean ended = false;
            while (!ended) {
                try {
                    Integer i = queue.take();
                    ended = i == End;
                    System.out.println(i);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ended = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        Thread pt = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
        Thread ct = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));
        // Start it all going.
        pt.start();
        ct.start();
        // Wait for it to finish.
        pt.join();
        ct.join();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Object[] monitors = new Object[10];
    final Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int num = i;
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Object mon = monitors[num];
                try {
                    synchronized (mon) {
                        mon.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println("Hello, world from thread " + num);
            }
        };
        Object o = new Object();
        threads[i] = t;
        monitors[i] = o;
        t.start();
    }

    final Object mon = monitors[5];
    synchronized (mon) {
        mon.notify();
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```